# SQL Server 2012 Query - Foreign Key from Same Table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table named `RoleDetails` with this structure:

```
ROLE_ID - PK , 
NAME ,
PARENT_ROLE_ID FK ,
CREATED_BY_ID , 
MODIFIED_BY_ID
```

The other table is `user_details`

```
USER_ID ,
USERNAME ,
FULLNAME
```

How do I query this table so that in the result set 
I get the RoleName, RoleId, ParentRoleId, ParentRoleName, CreatedByName and ModifiedByName.

So far I have tried:

```
SELECT 
    [ROLE_ID] AS ID, r.NAME AS [RoleName], 
    r.PARENT_ROLE_ID AS [ParentRoleID] , 
    (SELECT rd.NAME FROM dbo.ROLES rd 
     WHERE rd.ROLE_ID = r.PARENT_ROLE_ID ) AS [ParentRoleName], 
    CONCAT(ud.FIRST_NAME, ' ', ud.LAST_name) AS [CreatedByName] , 
    CONCAT(u.FIRST_NAME, ' ', u.LAST_name) AS [LastModifiedByName] 
FROM 
    dbo.ROLES r 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    user_details u ON r.MODIFIED_BY = u.USER_ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    dbo.USER_DETAILS ud ON r.CREATED_BY = ud.USER_ID 
WHERE 
    r.ROLE_ID = @iRoleID;
```

Comment: Yu join to the table itself, once to get the rolename and one to get the parent rolename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to join the `user_detail` table twice.  Once to get the create user and once to get the modify user.

```
SELECT    rd.Name, 
          rd.Role_ID, 
          rd.Parent_role_id,
          pr.Name, 
          ud.userName as CreatedByName, 
          udm.userName as ModifyByName
FROM RoleDetails as rd
INNER JOIN RoleDetails as pr
ON rd.Parent_Role_Id = pr.Role_id
INNER JOIN User_Detail as ud
on rd.Created_by_id = ud.user_id
INNER JOIN User_Detail as udm
ON rd.Modified_by_user = udm.user_id
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply Abe. I tried that..but I am not sure on how to get the parentrolename??

Comment: Stop posting SQL in the comments section.  What is your question?

Comment: I want to get ParentRoleName also in the same query @Abe

Comment: Just one more change Abe..if the Parent Role Id is null its not returning any rows for me..How can i handle so that it returns a row all the time

Comment: Change the join on RoleDetails to a `LEFT JOIN`